# Write a program that plays a simple dice game between the computer and the user. When the program runs, a loop should repeat 10 times

Tags: java

I am having trouble finding the result I'm looking for on this program

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
Roll 1:
User got: 6. Computer got: 3. User wins.
Roll 2:
User got: 6. Computer got: 2. User wins.
Roll 3:
User got: 6. Computer got: 1. User wins.
Roll 4:
User got: 5. Computer got: 5. Its a tie.
Roll 5:
User got: 1. Computer got: 1. Its a tie.
Roll 6:
User got: 6. Computer got: 6. Its a tie.
```

But this is the result I'm getting:

```
Computer won turn1
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn2
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn3
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn4
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn5
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn6
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn7
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn8
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn9
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
Computer won turn10
Computer was the grand winner, winningnullout of10turns
```

This is my code:

```
package HW4;

import java.util.Random;


public class DiceGame {

    
    

    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Random random = new Random();
        int totalNumberOfTurns = 10;
        int computerDie;
        int computerScore = 0;
        int userScore = 0;
    
        for( int turn = 1; turn <= totalNumberOfTurns; turn++) {
            computerDie = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
            
            
            int userDie1 = 0;
            
            
            if ( computerDie > userDie1 ) {
            computerScore = computerScore + 1;
                System.out.println("Computer won turn" + turn );
            } else if ( userDie1 > computerDie ) {
                System.out.println("User won turn" + turn );
                userScore = userScore + 1;
            } else { 
                System.out.println("turn" + turn + "was a tie" );
                
                
                
            }
            
            
            
            
        
            Object ComputerScore = null;
            Object userScore1 = null;
            if ( computerDie > userDie1 ) {
                System.out.println("Computer was the grand winner, winning" + ComputerScore + "out of" + totalNumberOfTurns + "turns" );
            
            
            } else if ( userDie1 > computerDie ) {
                System.out.println("User was the grand winner, winning" + ComputerScore + "out of" + totalNumberOfTurns + "turns" );
                
            } else if(ComputerScore == userScore1) { 
                System.out.println("It was a tie with computer winning" + ComputerScore + "turns and user winning" + userScore + "turns all out of" + totalNumberOfTurns ); 
            
            
        }
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your question is why in your code the computer always wins your game: It is because unlike the computer die roll where you use java.util.Random to generate that die roll all you do for the user is `int userDie1 = 0;`. If in a dice game where the higher number wins you let the computer roll numbers from 1 to 6 while always assigning the user the number 0, it certainly isn't a very fair or fun game ;)

Comment: Also you probably need to print `conputerScore` and not `ComputerScore`. What does `Object ComputerScore = null;` do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but if the issue is that the "grand winner" is displayed after each turn, that's because you are including it in your `for` loop.
Another thing with your code is that you do not take any input to `userDie1`. It always stays on `0` and therefore the `computerDie` value is always winning because it's bigger.
I also can't get why you are creating those two objects:

```
    Object ComputerScore = null;
    Object userScore1 = null;
```

You probably want to print the actual scores (userScore and compuierScore) instead of some `null` objects.

Comment: The problem is the result I am getting is different than the result  I am looking for. I put them both in the question.

Comment: But is that a problem with the format of the expected and actual outputs or with the code actually not working? My answer tells you how to make your code actually work. The formatting should be obvious - just change the strings you are printing.